# Make UIImages inside UIView Grow When Zooming

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiimage

I have a UIView Just like images aligned in gridlike view.
Created using the code.

```
for (int i=_farmView.bounds.origin.x; i<_farmView.bounds.size.width; i+=originalBagWidth*2) {

    for (int j=_farmView.bounds.origin.y; j<_farmView.bounds.size.height; j+=originalBagHeight*2) {

    //adding bag
        n+=1;

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(i, j, originalBagWidth, originalBagHeight);

    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    UIImage *image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"bag"];


    image = [self imageResize:image andResizeTo:v.bounds.size];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    [v addSubview:imageView];

    [_farmView addSubview: v];

    [v setBackgroundColor: [UIColor darkGrayColor]];

    }

}
```

And I have added proper Code for zooming the UIView using Pinch Recognizers. **Now when user zooms the UIView The Image Becomes unclear.**

> I want to grow the pixel size when zooming the UIView. How can i
>   achive this functionality

Note: The number of UIImages inside UIView and size of UIView is decided at runtime and cannot be predicted.

Comment: You zoom a UIView or UIImageView by embedding it in a UIScrollView and specifying the MaxZoom and implementing ViewForZooming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zoom in Scroll view with UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073940/zoom-in-scroll-view-with-uiimage)